# How can we develop the google earthengine based app in Python in our local machine?

Tags: python, django, google-earth-engine

I read the [documentation of google earth engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro). And I also see the github repo of the Earthengine api. I am exactly following the documentation. In my project file I added `config.py` file with my `service account id` and the `privatekey.json` file. I already write the following code and run it through terminal.

```
import ee
service_account = '<my-service-account-id>@tekson.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, 'privatekey.json')
ee.Initialize(credentials)
```

But it doesn't get initialized the earthengine. It always shows the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tekson/gee/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 338, in _execute_cloud_call
    return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
  File "/home/tekson/gee/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tekson/gee/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/algorithms?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "Permission denied.">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "config.py", line 4, in <module>
    ee.Initialize(credentials)
  File "/home/tekson/gee/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/__init__.py", line 123, in Initialize
    ApiFunction.initialize()
  File "/home/tekson/gee/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/apifunction.py", line 154, in initialize
    signatures = data.getAlgorithms()
  File "/home/tekson/gee/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 969, in getAlgorithms
    return _cloud_api_utils.convert_algorithms(_execute_cloud_call(call))
  File "/home/tekson/gee/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/data.py", line 340, in _execute_cloud_call
    raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Permission denied.
```

I don't understand how to use google service account. I also want to develop this app in Django later. Please anyone help me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If ee.Authenticate() works but ee.Initialize() gives you a permission denied error, it might be because you have a tracking blocker addon installed on chrome. Ghostery and EFF Privacy Badger are ones that have given me this error. After I turned them off, no error.

Comment: I will try check and response you back

Answer (score 1):

Your service account needs to be verified by Google to use service account. Alternatively, for development purpose locally just use `ee.Authenticate()` to authenticate your GEE account and `ee.Initialize()` to initialize it.

Comment: I created service account and it was verified. But I couldn't get the access. Always shows this error. I want to develop the gee based app like [this](http://resources-info.appspot.com/). But I dont know how to configure.

Comment: Highly doubt it was verified as permission denied error.

Comment: Tested on Mozilla firefox still getting the same error